# looking for an appropriate data structure(preferably Dictionary and List) for this scenario

Tags: c#, dictionary

In a method call an object is getting passed it.

From this object I can get two things:  an `ItemData` propery and a `Row` property so for example:

```
oPTL.ItemData, oPTL.Row
```

I want to have a data structure that each time this method is called it can update this data structure so for example one time `oPTL.ItemData` is `"Spread1"` and `oPTL.Row` is `2` so we should be able to save that `Spread1` has value `2`...next call for example we should be able to save "Spread3" has value 3..next call "Spread1" has ALSO value 4 , etc...

So it is like a `Dictionary<String,<List>>` but still I have problem with declaring and using it this way in the code, any code sample you can help me with?

Comment: Dictionary<String, List<int>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary where the values are Lists:

```
IDictionary<string, List<int>> rows = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

To populate it you can use this extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryDefaultExtension
{
    public static TValue GetOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        TKey key,
        Func<TValue> defaultValue)
    {
        TValue result;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            TValue value = defaultValue();
            dictionary[key] = value;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
d.GetOrDefault(oPTL.ItemData, () => new List<int>()).Add(oPTL.Row);
```

Comment: yes I wrote that in the question but the confusing this for me is that how I am adding those <int> parts to it? one method call I am adding value 3 to "Spread1" key, next method call adding value 2 to "Spread2" key then again next call adding value 4 to "Spread1" key assuming I am adding using a .Add method...so it thorws exception for third addition, right?

Comment: @BDotA: Read your question again... I think you wrote it without correct formatting.

Comment: yes right, I wrote it but after posting the format is changed somehow..thanks

Comment: @BDotA: It didn't change. You typed it with incorrect formatting. Did you check the preview before posting?

Comment: I put it in code tags but still showing it like that.  
I wanted to write Dictionary<String, List<int>>

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`Dictionary<string, List<int>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) - assuming your `.ItemData` and `.Row` properties are in fact `string` and `int` respectively.

When you read item with "Spread1" value, you first check whether such key already exists in dictionary by calling `.ContainsKey(string)` method. If so, you add new `Row` value - if not, you create new key with brand new list, like in example below:

```
var myItems = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
// ...
if (myItems.ContainsKey(newItem.ItemData))
{
    // myItems[newItem.ItemData] actually contains List<int> we created at some
    // point in the other part of if-else. 
    // The .Add method we call here belongs to List
    List<int> itemValues = myItems[newItem.ItemData];
    itemValues.Add(newItem.Row);
}
else
{
    myItems.Add(newItem.ItemData, new List<int> { newItem.Row });
}
```

**Edited** to add clarification with two `.Add` methods.

Comment: yes I wrote that in the question but the confusing this for me is that how I am adding those <int> parts to it? one method call I am adding value 3 to "Spread1" key, next method call adding value 2 to "Spread2" key then again next call adding value 4 to "Spread1" key assuming I am adding using a .Add method...so it thorws exception for third addition, right?

Comment: Is your previous code Wrong? I want to later be able to loop through it and say ok here is the items of values of this key, here is the values of that key, etc

Comment: @BDotA: previous code works exactly the same as this one - I just pulled list from under key to variable to distinguish two `.Add` methods used here: one from `Dictionary`, and second from `List`. `myItems[key]` will contain list of values, and you can do regular `List`-related stuff with it.